# How can I restore my profile on all sites?

Tags: support, profile-page

During Winter Bash 2014, on some of my accounts,
I played with editing my profile in various nutty ways using the 
**Save changes just for this community** button.
I was under the impression that later I can easily wipe out all the experiments on all the sites by using the **Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities** button on my "home site" ([Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/12390/janos)). 
But even if I use that button, it doesn't update the location field on [Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/17433/janos), or birth date on [English](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/24210/janos), just to give you a few examples, but there are many other experiments I did.

Is there a way to force update all the fields on all the sites?

Comment: Perhaps the button only copies across fields that *changed*. Perhaps changing all fields on Code Review, saving, then changing them back to their proper values would work, as a work-around?

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters, worked like a charm!

Answer (score 7):

As a workaround, I picked one of my accounts, and did this for the most important fields:

- Change the value of each field to something different from its current value, and click **Save changes just for this community**
- Change all the fields back to their correct value, and **Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities**

  - A confirmation dialog pops up with the list of the modified fields, asking if I want to update them on all sites, also informing that other ("unedited") fields will remain unchanged.

The update is instantaneous:
when I reload my profile on another site, the old experimental values were corrected immediately.

Since this behavior is not at all clear, perhaps a tooltip or some kind of hint would be nice next to the **Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities** button.

Comment: You shouldn't have to repeat it for each field. Clearing them all and then entering them all again should work fine. The system has changed so that it only copies over the values that changed on that site, to allow users to copy a change to all profiles without also copying other values in their profile that they wanted to be different.

Comment: @animuson good point, you're absolutely right, updated my answer